# NodeJs app with Java on Heroku

Tags: java, node.js, heroku

I have build my first NodeJS app with Express and am running it on C9 without any issues.

The app uses a Node Package (`easy-pdf-merge`) which requires at least Java 6.

On pushing my code up to Heroku I get an error at the point of the merge process saying I don't have Java install on this Dyno.

I have read a little about buildpacks but I'm not sure on the direction here.

Unless there is a simpler way to merge PDFs of course.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

Then redeploy by running

```
$ git commit -m "redeploy" --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

After the build, the JVM will be installed in your app, and available for use.

Comment: Thanks. The build succeeded but am now getting an error in the bowser, Standard Heroku "Application Error". This is the build result. Wondering if I need to make any other settings clarifications prior to build.
------>
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> JVM Common app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 100.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v26

Comment: oh, you probably need the jvm buildpack to be the first buildpack. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks very much, a little more testing to do but looks to have worked a treat. Thanks for the quick feedback too.